# Is it possible to bring data from cloud to on-prem using only Kafka Connectors API?

Tags: apache-kafka, cloud, apache-kafka-connect

I want to stream data from a cloud application that will publish logs to Kafka topics using producers and then send this data to a *HBase on-prem*. My doubt is if the *HBase Connector Sink* supports to send the data directly to my on-prem env *without installing Kafka on it*.

Comment: If you want to push data from Kafka to HBase using the HBase Sink Connector, then you don't have to install kafka on the machine(s) on which HBase is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka Connect is a separate process from the Kafka broker. You generally would not install it on the same machine, regardless. You will need to have your Kafka cluster somewhere, but whether on-premises or in the cloud, with the appropriate security config (firewalls etc) your Kafka Connect worker will be able to connect to the Kafka broker, and also to your HBase instance.

Comment: Actually, I will have Kafka on Cloud and HBase on-prem. I was thinking that I would must to build another Kafka Cluster in my on-prem server.